# Xcode crashes in preview but builds successfully and runs on simulator Xcode 14.3.1

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have been following along with a tutorial to build a protocols app that stores all the lab protocols I use. It was running well, until trying to build the code to populate the protocols. This particular file (ProtocolView) keeps crashing the preview, but it builds successfully and runs on the simulator. All I see on the preview is a white screen, with a red circle X saying Preview Crashed. I do not get any other errors, debug shows nothing, have tried adding breakpoint to get more info. Nothing. All other files run on preview and simulator as expected. I'm very new to Xcode, so really stumped with the lack of errors. I don't understand the crash report enough to understand what's going on.

Here is the code causing the issues:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct ProtocolView: View {
    var protocols: Protocols
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: protocols.image)) { image in image
                
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
                
            } placeholder: {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.7))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.gray).opacity(0.3)]),       `your text`startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text(protocols.name)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                    Text(protocols.description)
                }
            }
        }
        ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
        
    }

}

struct ProtocolView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            ProtocolView(protocols: Protocols.all[0])
            
        }
    }
    }
```